# What are the physical properties of the cation tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III)?

Tags: coordination-compounds, color

[image]

I am aware of the (pictured) structure of $\ce{[Co(en)3]^3+}$, but what are the physical properties of this ion? Namely, what is its colour?

Comment: @我叫叶莎 You can safely assume that the additional counter-ions have *no* effect on the solution’s overall colour. In general, for all transition metal complexes, it is *always* the central metal that determines the colour. $\ce{[Co(en3)]Cl3}$ is a salt formed of a complex cation with ‘standard’ counter-ions, hence why they are *outside* of the square brackets.

Comment: The Wikipedia page actually lists a few sources, one of which is the [*Acta Cryst. B* paper by Witiak, Clardy and Martin Jr](http://dx.doi.org/10.1107/S056774087200679X) who solved the structure of the nitrate. Who would have guessed that they obtained yellow-ish crystals? (CC @Joel)

Answer (score 3):

[Co(en)3]Cl3 was important in coordination chemistry for its stability and stereochemistry and  has been isolated as yellow, golden, needle like crystals. It is also described as a yellow, orange solid, soluble in water. The racemic complex is commonly obtained as the di or tri-hydrate although other hydrated forms are known.(Ref:Wikipedia)

The computed physical properties and other chemical data are well documented on @pubchem.

Comment: I am well aware. But I wanted to know more about the cation [Co(en)3]3+ (tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III)), not the compound  [Co(en)3]Cl3 (tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III) chloride).

Comment: Oh OK, then why even mention the chloride anions in the structure?

Comment: I couldn't find any picture of the structure of Co[en]3 without the chloride anions mentioned. There is actually very little easily accessible information about Co[en]3 alone as a cation and not as a component of a compound. Thus, I asked this question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the site I mentioned @pubchem? Or @chemspider.